# Popoper and NSImageView

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin.mac

I'm having issues displaying a popover in my application. In this case, I cannot get the image to show.

This is my popover controller:

```
public partial class ImagePopoverController : NSViewController
{
    NSImageView _imageView = new NSImageView();
    // Called when created from unmanaged code
    public ImagePopoverController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    // Called when created directly from a XIB file
    [Export ("initWithCoder:")]
    public ImagePopoverController (NSCoder coder) : base (coder)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    // Call to load from the XIB/NIB file
    public ImagePopoverController (NSImageView imageView) : base ("ImagePopover", NSBundle.MainBundle)
    {
        this._imageView = imageView;
        Initialize ();          
    }

    // Shared initialization code
    void Initialize ()
    {

    }

    public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        base.AwakeFromNib();
        View.AddSubview(_imageView);
    }

    //strongly typed view accessor
    public new ImagePopover View {
        get {
            return (ImagePopover) base.View;
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the popover it's diplayed where it should be, but it does not show any image in it.

```
NSImageView imageView = new NSImageView();
imageView.Image = new NSImage(String.Format("cache/{0}.png", User.PID));
ImagePopoverController Controller = new ImagePopoverController(imageView);
                 
imagePopover.ContentViewController = Controller;
ImagePopover.Show(new RectangleF(0, 0, 0, 0), View.View, NSRectEdge.MinYEdge);
```

Comment: Do you have any `NSImageView` inside `ImagePopover` view (added in xib or created from code)?

Comment: @Serg tried, both via code and manually adding a control in the xbix. This is driving me mad

Comment: You should not create an NSImageView from outside. Setup an ImageView in the xib and create an outlet for it. Only pass the NSImage to the ImagePopover controller and assign it to the image view (after the xib had loaded ofcourse)

Comment: Thanks to both! Originally I was doing what svn was saying but for some reason both VS and Xcode crashed upon debug. I deleted and recreated the xib and it worked, so maybe there was some other issue.